# WAMP Not showing project index page

Tags: php, wamp

I have a directory under "Your Projects" that has an index file in it. I can not get the index page to display. The localhost url turns into the name of the directory and nothing displays.

I researched this and found crazy amounts of different solutions. I found that editing some files as ADMIN to create a virtual host I believe should work. I am just looking for direction on how to set this up so my websites will show.

I have:

- windows 8 64bit
- Wamp version 2.5 64bit
- apache version 2.4.9
- php version 5.5.12
- mysql version 5.6.17
- WAMP ICON IS GREEN
- Hosts active lines

  ```
  127.0.0.1       localhost
  127.0.0.1       localhost
  ```

I have access to localhost homepage and phpmyadmin

No error message.

Anti virus is Kaspersky

wamp is installed to

```
c:\wamp
```

Comment: Read on http://forum.wampserver.com/list.php?2 - particularly the one with "READ BEFORE YOU ASK A QUESTION"

Comment: I updated it, from what I read there is 2 files that needed to be edited or something. Nothing I found gave clear insructions

Comment: I installed Wamp a month ago. I was up and running in 5 mins. If you made any changes to any system files and didn't restart all services, then they won't take effect. Make sure you chose the right install file too.

Comment: I didnt edit anything, hmm

Comment: Did you reboot your computer after installing it?

Comment: Yes the whole thing, I did of research(google) and there is a bunch if people who had the same problem but they all fixed it a different way it seemed

Comment: How are you trying to access the file, `http://localhost/index.php` or `file://`?

Comment: This post will explain why and tell you how to create Virtual Hosts for each of your projects. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23665064/project-links-do-not-work-on-wamp-server/23990618#23990618